# How can I have tor and tor-browser both installed?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, ubuntu

I already have install `tor-browser` installed and working on my Ubuntu. However when I try to install `tor` to use `torify` on terminal, I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  mint-backgrounds-rebecca
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster xul-ext-torbutton socat tor-arm polipo privoxy apparmor-utils
Recommended packages:
  tor-geoipdb torsocks
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tor
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/787 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,662 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 341697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tor_0.2.4.27-1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tor (0.2.4.27-1build0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.27-1build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is happening because of the conflict with already installed package `tor-browser`. But I don't want to remove the browser.

How can I use `torify` along with tor browser install on Linux?

Comment: Why not use Tor from TBB without installing another one? As can you see, the Tor's version that you're trying to install is an old one.. so try out with Tor from TBB that is located in `tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor`

Comment: You don't have to configure Tor Browser to install standalone tor. Instructions for installing tor on Ubuntu are [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to uninstall the dodgy `tor-browser` package and either use [`torbrowser-launcher`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=torbrowser-launcher) from the Ubuntu package repos or download Tor Browser directly from the [Tor Project website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) or [one of it's other sources](https://gettor.torproject.org/).

This is important, many of these `tor-browser` packages ship in a form that makes it impossible for the native updater, running as the user, to update the tor browser and to compound this issue it's common that updates are severely delayed, if they happen *at all*! This leaves users running old, vulnerable versions of Tor Browser *indefinitely*.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved exactly this problem on Ubuntu and Windows just like a charm. Here is what you need to do : compile Tor, I've used git source tree, you can use just stable version, and install it in a dedicated folder. I've used `/usr/tor` on Ubuntu and `c:\tor` on Windows. After that I've made a shortcut/symlink for a tor binary AND `torrc`(!!important part!!) for Tor Browser Bundle inside it's directories, and - it works! =) Single-point configured, just running in the way I wish it to run. To find out where is your tor and torrc just run simple file search by name - it will show you the path.